# a closed set projected

Tags: calculus, vectors

I would like some help with vector calculus.

I was asked to find a closed set in a plane that when projected on the X axis is not closed.

any insight will be helpful.

Comment: Hint. Points far apart in their $y$ coordinates (make them integers) can have x coordinates with a limit not in the projection on the axis. (Please edit question to change "group" to "set" and "cast" to "project".)

Comment: hey thanks for answering. can you give me an example please?

Comment: You got a hint. First try to elaborate on it..